# 3D Geometry Proof on spheres (high school)

Tags: geometry

I need help on how to prove this statement. I've asked a classmate and he has no clue.

"All great circles of a sphere are congruent."

The definition of a great circle of sphere is "the intersection of the sphere and a secant plane that contains the center of the sphere." My approach was to have the two great circles intersect on some line and use similar triangles but I don't know how this would work.

Comment: May I ask you what do you mean by being congruent?

Comment: Can't you map them on each other by a rotation about the center of the sphere?

Comment: @Person: You would have a nice explanation in Riemannian Geometry, if you knew that.

Comment: My book doesn't say anything about what it means for two great circles to be congruent. We're using "Geometry for Christian Schools" from Bob Jones press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The planes that cut out two different great circles from the sphere intersect in a line (through the center, which both planes contain).  There is a rotation with that line as axis, carrying the first plane onto the second. It moves the sphere to itself, because it keeps the center in place and preserves all distances.  This rotation is a distance-preserving motion of the space carrying one great circle to the other.

Comment: @ zyx: Good insight but I need to write something in a two proof column. Could you elaborate more on rotation and what you mean by "preserving all distances"?

Comment: @Person: Do you know what a transformation is?

Comment: Transformation is not covered until a later chapter. We're not really supposed to use transformation for this excercise and no, I don't know what that term really is.

Comment: If you place the picture of the intersecting planes so that the planes are perpendicular to the paper (so they would be drawn as lines intersecting at a point), take a 2-d rotation of the "paper" plane carrying one line to the other, and do the same rotation, in parallel, on all planes parallel to the planes (that is, perpendicular to the line of intersection).  This lets you build a 3-d rotation if you are familiar with 2-d rotations.

Comment: @ zyx: I looked up the definition of transformation and rotations. I am familiar with 2D rotations now. My question is if we're doing a 3D rotation, how would you describe the composition of two reflections across two planes?

Comment: In the same way -- what is happening in one plane $P$ perpendicular to the two intersecting ones, is repeated in all the other planes that have the same orientation relative to the line and the intersecting planes (and so are parallel to $P$).  But you should think of rotation as a continuous motion, not the combination of two abrupt mirror reflections, though the end result would be the same.  Try moving physical objects by a rotation in space, but imagine that each object carries a rigid 3-d grid attached to it and moves the whole space along with it.

Comment: I see what you mean now zyx. I have the image in my head. Thanks!